# Disable 'Invisibility on LAN' - NordVPN Linux

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, vpn, 32-bit

NordVPN on Windows has a feature called 'Invisibility on LAN', which, if disabled, allows the device connected to the VPN to still be discovered by other devices on the local network.

When this feature is *enabled*, the device is not visible on the local network and you can't access things such as your router page, printer, etc.

It seems that, by default, my Ubuntu computer, while connected to VPN, is not discoverable on the local network, and as such, I can't access my router or any local devices. In the settings, I also can't see any option called 'Invisibility on LAN' or something with a similar name.

How can I make my computer discoverable on the local network, but still be connected to the VPN while acessing the internet, like I can on Windows?

Comment: This seems to be more of a feature of NordVPN than Windows or Ubuntu.  Nord VPN  will be able to help more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Registered here just to answer this question. Long time lurker.

I had the same problem. There is no flag/option for the "invisibility on LAN" feature, however, you can whitelist your entire subnet or a range of it and it effectively fixes the issue.

In my case, I implemented:

nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.1.0/24

This immediately opened up my LAN with NordVPN enabled.